# Dynamic property type based on value of anther property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, complex-data-types

How to best implement a property with a dynamic data type depending on the value of another property?

I have a class for an `Order` with two properties `OrderType` (enum) and `OrderStatus` (enum)

The problem is that the data type for `OrderStatus` is different depending on the value `OrderType`

```
public class Order
{
    // Enums
    public enum OrderTypes { Restaurant, Grocery, Wallet }

    public enum RestaurantOrderStatus { OrderPlaced, Pending, Preparing, ReadyForPickup OnTheWay, Cancelled }
    public enum GroceryOrderStatus { OrderPlaced, Enqueued, Preparing, OnTheWay, Cancelled, Returning }
    public enum WalletOrderStatus { OrderPlaced, OnTheWay, Cancelled }

    // Properties
    public OrderTypes OrderType { get; set; }
    public OrderStatuses OrderStatus { get; set; } // How to set a dynamic data type (different enum)?
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best approach to do this?

- Using Generic Type?
- Using [Builder Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder)?

Comment: The Order is the base class and then Restaurant, Grocery, Wallet would be inherited classes

Comment: @jdweng I thought about that, but the issue is that I need to provide a single `Order` class to the ASP.NET Action Method in the API controller.

Comment: @jdweng The API is expecting a list of orders `List<Order>`

Comment: You don't need all those enums, just create a single base-class `Order` as jdweng suggests and let `Restaurant`, `Grocery` and `Wallet` inherit it. Than you can still put all kinds of orders into a single collection, but every order itself knows what it is. You don't need any `OrderTypes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement a Generic Type.

```
public class Order<T> where T : Enum
{
    public Enums.OrderTypes OrderType { get; set; }
    public T OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Enums
{
    public enum OrderTypes { Restaurant, Grocery, Wallet }

    public enum RestaurantOrderStatus { OrderPlaced, Pending, Preparing, ReadyForPickup, OnTheWay, Cancelled }
    public enum GroceryOrderStatus { OrderPlaced, Enqueued, Preparing, OnTheWay, Cancelled, Returning }
    public enum WalletOrderStatus { OrderPlaced, OnTheWay, Cancelled }
}

public class UseCase
{
    public static void UseLike()
    {
        Enums.OrderTypes orderType = Enums.OrderTypes.Grocery;

        switch (orderType)
        {
            case Enums.OrderTypes.Restaurant:
                _ = new Order<Enums.RestaurantOrderStatus>();
                break;
            case Enums.OrderTypes.Grocery:
                _ = new Order<Enums.GroceryOrderStatus>();
                break;
            case Enums.OrderTypes.Wallet:
                _ = new Order<Enums.WalletOrderStatus>();
                break;
        }

    }
}
```